# Webpage in picture box

Tags: vb6

One way to open a webpage I know is in IE window, like this:

```
Shell _
    "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE " _
    & "http://maps.google.com/maps?q= " & b & "" _
    , vbMaximizedFocus
```

I want to open the same thing in an image or a picture box instead.
Will a user be able to browse the map and use zoom in/zoom out functions like doing it online then?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do this.

1. <strike>Use a 3rd party library to convert the web page to an image.</strike>
2. Use the Web Browser control. [Here's a video on how to use it.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EhDi6-Rp_yM)

Comment: can you tell me how i can do that im still really new

Comment: @user2275365 i posted a video link.

Comment: another problem sorry...i dont have 'Microsoft Internet Controls' in my components

Comment: there are plenty examples online on how to use it.